# Thymeleaf th:field handle null with input text but not with radio, why?

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I'm new to Thymeleaf and until there the documentation helped me a lot. But I'm stuck on a form since a few hours and a lot of research! I'm preloading data test in a HTML form (it will come from DB later).

*Java Spring Controller*

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foobar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String foobar(@RequestParam(value="bar", required = true) String id, Model model) {

    Obj foo = new Obj();
    foo.setPropertyOne(1.71f);
    foo.setPropertyTwo(null);

    model.addAttribute("foo", foo);

    return "foobar";
}
```

The properties go on and on. I didn't put any @Annotation on my POJO Obj. (?)

I was happy to discover th:field who works like a charm on input text.

```html
<form th:object="${foo}" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{propertyOne}" />
</form>
```

If there is text data it's preloaded, if there is not (set to null or even not set at all), the input stays empty.

Let's move to the radio type.

```html
<input value="false" type="radio" th:field="*{propertyX}"/>
<input value="true" type="radio" th:field="*{propertyX}"/>
```

It still works, false or true checked depending on the Boolean. But if it's not set or set to null, I've got **org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputRadioFieldAttrProcessor** ; obviously Thymeleaf doesn't handle null on RadioField?

I tried to use th:checked instead, but doesn't handle null neither:

```html
<input value="false" type="radio" th:checked="!*{propertyX}"/>
<input value="true" type="radio" th:checked="*{propertyX}"/>
```

I also tried different expressions with th:if but didn't manage to get something working.

I hope I gave you enough information! Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is propertyX a `boolean` or a capital B `Boolean`?

Comment: @Metroids First I used boolean but understood I couldn't set it to null so I tried with Boolean.

Comment: Hmm, well I know nulls do work with radio fields and `<input value="false" type="radio" th:field="*{propertyX}"/>` is the correct way to do it.  Can you post more (or possibly the entire) exception? That line you posted doesn't contain anything helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Metroids, I was about to edit my first message to add the entire exception. It was a huge one, usually by reading it I find the solution... I probably didn't read it thorougly enough. :x

I read it again before posting and all of a sudden I realized, here on the third line: `org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)`

As I told you I first used boolean, then Boolean but forgot to change the getter! It was still `isPropertyX` and not `getPropertyX`, I suppose Thymeleaf couldn't access the method then!

It's working now. Thanks anyway, I got here thanks to our exchange!